# For loop help, Storing data in one long string

Tags: java, loops

Here is a for loop I am working on:

```
for (int count=1; count<= numofnames; count++){
    System.out.println("Enter a name?");
temp= scan.nextLine();}
```

temp is a String, how do I keep all of the previous names in one long string instead of it changing the value of temp every time it loops. I basically want X amount of names in one long string called temp.

Answer (score 3):

You may concat input strings via `StringBuilder` for good performance. Altough you migh want to use faster input handler than `Scanner`. `BuffferedReader` would suffice.

```
String line;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while((line = scan.nextLine()) != null)
   sb.append(line);
```

using `BufferedReader`

```
String line;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))){
    while((line = br.nextLine()) != null)
       sb.append(line);
}catch(IOException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reassigning the value of temp, you could concatenate to it using, for example:

```
temp += scan.nextLine();
```